# Retain/preserve pom xml structure[element order] while writing pom file using MavenXpp3Reader/MavenXpp3Writer

Tags: java, api, maven, pom.xml

I want to remove only the version number element from dependency as I plan to move that to parent pom. When I do that, entire pom.xml getting rearranged. But, I want to present original pom.xml structure which will help to compare when checked in into git.

I use below code now.

```
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
pomStream = new FileInputStream(pomF);
Model model = reader.read(pomStream);

       // update properties 

model.setProperties(modelProperties);
MavenXpp3Writer writer = new MavenXpp3Writer();
writer.write(new FileWriter(pomF), model);
```

How to preserve original structure while writing the pom.xml after making changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with these readers, they can only transform XML to Java instances and vice versa. The hard way is implementing the transformation with XLST, but I'd go for the good ol' search and replace with a proper texteditor or IDE.
If you think you'll do this often, consider having a look at https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/